# Cannot plot separate qq-plots, but can plot a combined

Tags: r, plot, statistics, qq

I cannot plot my qq-plots for individual genders, but I can plot them combined. It keeps saying, that: "y is empty or has only NAs", and I cannot seem to figure out how I should change my code. You can see some of my code down below:

```
## Read data
D<-read.table("bmi1_data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",as.is=TRUE)

## Divide data into two subsets according to gender
Dfemale<-subset(D,gender == 0)
Dmale<-subset(D,gender==1)
```

I have calculated BMI earlier in my code.

```
## New variable 'logbmi' with log-transformed BMI
D$logbmi <- log(D$bmi)
```

It can plot this:

```
## qq-plot of log-transformed BMI
qqnorm(D$logbmi)
qqline(D$logbmi)
```

But it cannot plot this:

```
## qq-plot of log-transformed BMI for females
qqnorm(Dfemale$logbmi)
qqline(Dfemale$logbmi)
```

and also this does not work:

```
## qq-plot of log-transformed BMI for males
qqnorm(Dmale$logbmi)
qqline(Dmale$logbmi)
```

I hope this makes sense, because stackoverflow wouldn't let me insert my whole code. Thank you

Comment: Please post part of your data so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot plot this". What happens if you try?